# How can I create a table of variable names and their levels?

Tags: r

I am trying to make a table with two columns: 1) Variable name, 2) the levels of that variable.

Here is a dummy code for the dataframe:

```
Data <- data.frame(Gender = sample(c("male", "female", "other"),10, replace = TRUE), Age = sample(1:10), Happiness = sample(c("Very","Some","None"), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

So essentially I just want a table that says:

**Variable Name   |    Levels**

Gender         |     1=Male, 2=Female, 3=Other

Age          |       Numeric

Happiness     |     1=Very, 2=Some, 3=None

How can I do this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea via base R can be,

```
data.frame(Levels = sapply(Data, function(i){i1 <- levels(i); 
              ifelse(length(i1) > 0, paste0(seq_along(i1), ' = ', i1, collapse = ' '), class(i))}))

#                                 Levels
#Gender    1 = female 2 = male 3 = other
#Age                             integer
#Happiness    1 = None 2 = Some 3 = Very
```

Comment: @danibradford If this solution works for you, please consider accepting it (by clicking the tick mark next to it) so we can consider this issue resolved. Thanks